# Count Rows Until Finding Specific String

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Excel VBA to count the number of rows until I hit a specific string and set a variable equal to it.

Something like:

```
Dim i as Integer

i = Worksheets("Scope Phase Document").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find("FACTS - What are we measuring?").Count
```

I know this isn't the correct syntax and I'm probably missing other stuff, but just using the different functions I currently know, this is what I would hope would do the trick.  I get

> Run-time error '91' saying "Object variable or With block variable not
>   set

I have tried a few different ways of doing it, but can't figure out a way that doesn't result in an error.

So I want to start at A1 and count all the rows down until I reach the specific string "FACTS - What are we measuring?".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer MATCH, but if the match is not found it throws an error. So we need to test for that:

```
Dim i As Long
i = 0
On Error Resume Next
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("FACTS - What are we measuring?", ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If i > 0 Then
 ' do you stuff with i
End If
```

Comment: Oh excellent!  This works just great.  Thank you very much Scott, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want `MATCH()`:

```
=MATCH("FACTS - What are we measuring?",A:A,0)
```

It returns the row number of matched string.

Comment: Ah okay.  I will have to to remember that for the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine except you should use the `Row` property. The `Count` property as you have used it will return 1 because the `Find` method returns one cell (the first cell where a match is found).

```
Dim i as Integer

i = Worksheets("Scope Phase Document").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find("FACTS - What are we measuring?").Row
```

Like Scott mentioned, if your text is not found, Excel will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
Sub rowcounter()

Dim i As Integer

Range("A1").Select

i = 0

Do

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

i = i + 1

Loop Until Selection.Value = "FACTS - What are we measuring?"

MsgBox "rows count is " & i

End Sub
```